# Get data from baseurl with ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, http-get, base-url

I want to send information to the screen id that information sent to it by the echo. I get this interaction takes place via ajax would like to receive information from the entire screen again displays. Please help

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#button').click(function(){
    var id = $(this).attr('id_1');

    $.ajax({ 
        url:'get.php',
        type: 'get',
        data:{id:id},
        success: function(data){
        //alert(data);
      $('#result').html(data);
        }

         });
    });
});


  <body>
    <?php if(isset($_GET['id'])){echo $_GET['id'];}?>

    <a href="#" id="button" id_1="20">test</a>
    <div id="result"></div>
```

after result

```
    20
<a>test</a>****------------------------------>Is repeated
<a>test</a>
```

but i want just this result

```
     20
```

Comment: So, what is the problem you are facing?

Comment: you have to remove the results at each time you make a click function.that avoids repeating $('#result').empty().call this start of  click $('#button').click(function(){ $('#result').empty()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. It will displays the output as you said.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#button').click(function(){
        var id = $(this).attr('id_1');

        $.ajax({ 
            url:'get.php',
            type: "get",
            data:{id:id},
            success: function(data){
                $('#result').html(data);
            }

             });
        });
    });

    </script>

    <div id="result">
 <a  href="#" id="button" id_1="20">test</a></div>
```

This is get.php

```
  <?php if(isset($_GET['id'])){echo 'hi';}
  ?>
```

if you want exit:20 as output, then change get.php as

```
 <?php if(isset($_GET['id'])){echo 'exit : '.$_GET['id'];}
    ?>
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer, but again, as I see it when I run the command, the output is only about hi or 20(id_1) i just want

Comment: If you want only hi as output, please change the get.php as edited above

Comment: Tag <a  href="#" id="button" id_1="20">test</a> Is repeated I do not want to repeat again please please if you can help me I just want my output 20 give you this kind of work is not at all

Comment: if you include the code <a href="#" id="button" id_1="20">test</a>  inside the div result, then it will not be displayed again. Have a look at my code

Comment: I designed a site that <id> sends to the screen, but since php is using the address bar shows, like by ajax If you have id Get the address is not shown, but with this code everything on the site is repeated but normally php is done This is my code does not work

Comment: http://www.islamicstudies.info/tafheem.php?sura=4&verse=11&to=14           For example, look at this site, I'd do the same thing with Ajax, but do not show the url

Comment: If you don't want to show the code in url, then use type: "post", in ajax function instead of get method.

Comment: but i want use ajax for sending data

Comment: In your ajax function change the line type:"get", to type:"post",. If my answer is wrong, I think I can't understand your question clearly

Comment: Thank you very much for taking time and trouble, but in the end if I could find a solution please let me know the issue entirely for a site is a Within the same page that we want to send some information to get the same information and it should exit without printing the address bar using Ajax

Comment: To call the ajax function, you need to use different page. You can't get or post the values within the same page using ajax call. If you use the same page for ajax call, the whole page content will be displayed as output.

Answer (score 1):

**Change you type as GET in AJAX**

```
$('#result').empty();
$.ajax({ 
    url:'get.php?id='+ id,
    type: "GET",
    //data:{id:id},
    success: function(data){
    //alert(data);
  $('#result').html(data);
    }

     });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, but the result was repeated inside the tag <a> this page

Comment: @user3445955  you can check the code. i updated to avoid repeating